# how to get all values from dropdown from web application in blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I want get all values of dropdown and want to store them somewhere. from follwing NASDAQ site  https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ge/historical  i want get all values of Timeframe and want to somewhere so that i can use those values one b one in loop and get the values of stock for all timeframe. Click below image [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGwCx.png)

Answer (score 2):

It's not that easy to get each of the values, but it's not impossible. First you can get all the values in a Data Item as text. If you spy the element, you will notice that the attribute `Value` contains what you want. So you will need to use a read stage and get this specific attribute's value (you can ignore the PDF elements):

[image]

Doing so will give you the following:

[image]

The problem with this is that you cannot use this in a loop. One way around would be to split on space:

[image]

And the resulting collection (I called it Split Values) will look like this:

[image]

But it's not quite there yet. You should however be able to use this collection to get the collection you need (or use it directly).

If you use it directly, I would say it should look like this:

[image]

`Empty?` has the expression `[Split Values.words]=""` (notice the last row is blank)

`Value is number` has the expression `IsNumber([Split Values.words])`

`Set Current Item as Number` has expression `[Split Values.words]` with store value `Current Item`.

`Append word to Current Item` has expression `[Current Item]&" "&[Split Values.words]` with store value `Current Item`.

Comment: Alternative approach would be to use regex to split that text into collection.